# QML - Cannot assign to non-existent property "style"

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquickcontrols, qtquickcontrols2

I'm using Qt 5.10.1 with Qt Creator 4.5.1 and the **style** property is never available in elements.

For example, as shown here [ButtonStyle QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-buttonstyle.html) , I would like to do:

```
Button {
    text: "A button"
    style: ButtonStyle {...}
}
```

But, I get the error:

> Cannot assign to non-existent property "style"

I tried with a rectangle, progressbar and I get the same error.

**Edit #1:**

I do have all these imports. If the import was missing, I would get the error on **ButtonStyle** , but the error is on **style**.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are 2 types of Buttons in QML:

- Button Qt Quick Controls 2: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-button.html
- Button Qt Quick Controls: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html

In your case, you are importing the Qt QuickControls 2 Button: `import QtQuick.Controls 2.3`, and that Button does not have the `style` attribute.

If you need to use the *style* you must import:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
```

instead of:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
```

---

If you are using items from Qt Quick Controls and Qt Quick Controls 2 you could separate them using a namespace:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3 as QQC2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as QQC1

QQC1.Button {
    text: "A button"
    style: ButtonStyle {...}
}

QQC2.another_item_of_Qt_Quick_Controls2{
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a great and clear answer.  I don't understand why some people downvoted this question. The documentation wasn't clear about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize `Qt Quick Controls 2` button by modifying its two visual items of background and content item:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-button

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Button {
    id: control
    text: qsTr("Button")

    contentItem: Text {
        text: control.text
        font: control.font
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
        color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        elide: Text.ElideRight
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 100
        implicitHeight: 40
        opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0.3
        border.color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
        border.width: 1
        radius: 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  importing `QtQuick.Controls.Styles`

```
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
Button {
    text: "A button"
    style: ButtonStyle {...}
}
```