# qt Quick Button palette does not works with Qt6

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

This used to work till Qt 5.15

```
Button {
    text: "Test button"
        
    palette {
        button: "green"
    }
}
```

But not with Qt6

Comment: show the imports

Comment: import QtQuick
        
import QtQuick.Window
        
import QtQuick.Controls

Answer (score 0):

In Qt5 there are 2 groups of items with very common elements as I explain in this post: [QML - Cannot assign to non-existent property "style"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263604/qml-cannot-assign-to-non-existent-property-style/49264019#49264019).

In Qt5 the solution was not to confuse the imports (for example use a namespace) but in Qt6 the first group was removed so now only Qt Quick Controls 2 is used and that group has a different way of setting the [button style](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-button):

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Button {
    id: control
    text: qsTr("Button")

    contentItem: Text {
        text: control.text
        font: control.font
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
        color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        elide: Text.ElideRight
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 100
        implicitHeight: 40
        opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0.3
        border.color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
        border.width: 1
        radius: 2
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not looks good. If we have to use rectangle to change background then what is the purpose of Button.

Comment: @Harris The Button is an Item that uses other items to define its appearance, a rectangle only draws the rectangle but does not have the signals and other aspects of the button. You just have to modify contentItem or background, you don't need both.